# How to get the absolute path of a file/image

Tags: qt, qml

I need absolute path of a file suppose my path structure is like

```
 -myProject_Folder
    ~assets_folder
       -images_folder
    ~demo_folder
        -first_page.qml
```

And suppose I need to upload an image[from images_folder]on first_page.qml

```
                    Image {
                        id: img
                        height:200
                        width:200
                        source:"../assets/images/imageName.png" 
                        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
```

i have tried Qt.resolvedUrl (URL) but on my map pages this is not working, on Android and iOS mobile the images is not showing.
Please do suggest something only in qml

Comment: From time to time I like to use this snippet: `QDirIterator it(":", QDirIterator::Subdirectories); while (it.hasNext()) { qDebug() << it.next(); }` which will output all available resource files.

Comment: My first recommendation is to put all image assets in a .qrc file rather than access them directly from the file system. But I also wonder if this will work: `source: "file:///assets/images/imageName.png"`? Note that I dropped the `../` because I think paths should be relative to your .pro file, not whatever .qml file you're in.